# How to use OS environment variables in rebar3

Tags: makefile, erlang, relx, rebar3

I currently have a rebar3 based erlang application, it consists of an erlang backend and a javascript frontend. To combine the frontend and backend build systems I use a makefile. My rebar.config looks like this:

**rebar.config**:

```
...
{relx, [{release, {pgserver_dev, "0.1.0"},[pgserver]}
       ]},
       {dev_mode, true},
       {include_erts, false},
       {extended_start_script, true}
]}.
```

**Makefile**:

```
...
release:
    @echo "creating release"
    rebar3 release
    ln -sf _build/$(PROFILE)/rel/$(APP)_dev/bin/$(APP)_dev /.run-$(APP)-$(PROFILE)
```

I'd like to use environment variables in the *rebar.config* file to control parameters like e.g. the version -- `{pgserver_dev, "0.1.0"}` when creating a release. If I specify a variable: `VERSION` the build could look like this:

**rebar.config**:

```
...
{relx, [{release, {pgserver_dev, os:getenv("VERSION")},[pgserver]}
       ]},
       {dev_mode, true},
       {include_erts, false},
       {extended_start_script, true}
]}.
```

So, is it possible to use linux environment variables in relx/rebar3?

P.S.: It is not possible with `os:getenv()`, the build fails with:

```
===> Error reading file rebar.config: 15: bad term
```

Comment: Did you check the [rebar3 dynamic configuration documentation](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/dynamic-configuration)?

Comment: @Steve Vinoski: Thanks Steve, this seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Must have overlooked it in the documentation until now....

Answer (score 1):

You can make a [*dynamic configuration*](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/dynamic-configuration) by using a `rebar.config.script`. It will give you an Erlang script where you can update or add terms inside the `rebar.config`. You can search for `rebar.config.script` on Github to find examples. I found one [here](https://github.com/skuapso/skuapso/blob/3bde18ac2d6bd812450127e5f5304f4cdd64e7e7/rebar.config.script).